# Multiple Databindings on single textbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I was trying to create a way to show different data columns in a single text box by a drop down option.

Like when I chose "first" on one and "first" on the second one the text box will bind specified columns where this is the "first first" case.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
             If ComboBox2.Text = "First" Then
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - first first < Columns name 
             elseif combox2.text = "second" then 
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - first second

             End If
        elseif combox1.text ="second" then
             If ComboBox2.Text = "First" Then
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - second first
             elseif combox2.text = "second" then 
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - second second

             End If
        elseif combox1.text ="third" then
             If ComboBox2.Text = "First" Then
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - third first
             elseif combox2.text = "second" then 
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - third second

             End If
             else
             If ComboBox2.Text = "First" Then
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - fourth first
             elseif combox2.text = "second" then 
                  Textbox1.text = databindings - fourth second

             End If
        End If
```

I know there is a property option for that but it is only one binding per textbox.
Does someone know what I can do to make it work or is it impossible?

I'm using data grid and binding navigator and using only 1 table with Visual Studion 10 and Access 13 as database.